# AddAttribute set default date as current date

Tags: magento-1.9

```
$installer->addAttribute("customer", "creation_date",  array(
  "type"          => "varchar",
  "backend"       => "eav/entity_attribute_backend_array",
  "label"         => "",
  "input"         => "date",
  "source"        => "module/attribute_source_customerproducts",
  "visible"       => false,
  "required"      => false,
  "default"       => "",
  "frontend"      => "",
  "unique"        => false,
  "note"          => ""
));
```

How can I set the default date to the current date? if I would set it in the "default" it would always be the date when the attribute was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's not possible within attribute creation.

I would observe `customer_save_before` event and set date there:

```
public function customerSaveBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
    # new customer
    if (!$customer->getId()) {
        $customer->setCreationDate(Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:**

You can set "right" backend model in you install script ... like

```
$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'my_creation_date',  array(
  'type'          => 'datetime',
  'backend'       => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_time_created',
  'input'         => 'text',
  'visible'       => false,
  'required'      => false,
  'unique'        => false,
));
```

Either

> eav/entity_attribute_backend_time_created

```
public function beforeSave($object)
{
    $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
    $date = $object->getData($attributeCode);
    if (is_null($date)) {
        if ($object->isObjectNew()) {
            $object->setData($attributeCode, Varien_Date::now());
        }
    } else {
        // convert to UTC
        $zendDate = Mage::app()->getLocale()->utcDate(null, $date, true, $this->_getFormat($date));
        $object->setData($attributeCode, $zendDate->getIso());
    }

    return $this;
}
```

or

> eav/entity_attribute_backend_time_updated

```
public function beforeSave($object)
{
    $object->setData($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode(), Varien_Date::now());
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
"default"       => "NOW()",
```

Comment: Will try it out!

Comment: Tested ... it will just add `NOW()` as default string.

Comment: Ah ok, that's unfortunate. Did you also try with `"type" => "datetime"`?

Comment: NOW() is converted to 'NOW()' (with single quotes), and generates an error:
`1067 Invalid default value for 'created_at'`